# "Share this on..." URLs

Tags: hyperlink, social-networking

I have to create a bunch of these "Share this on" Technorati, Digg, Facebook, Reddit, del.icio.us, StumbleUpon, MySpace and so on. It is very easy to find online icons for this task, but it is a little more difficult to find what URLs I should link.

Is there any updated list of all these services? Of course I could copy them from other sites having this, but I am not sure they are updated, and moreover maybe there is some GET parameter I want to set differently.

EDIT: I do not really care for services doing this for me, I just need the addresses. Among the reasons I do not like the external services is the fact that I can't customize the buttons.

Comment: addthis.com has a lot of various customizations, including buttons. Another great advantage to use external services such as addthis.com is that you get click statistics for nothing.

Comment: I don't care for statistics. And sincerely I do not see how to customize buttons on addthis.com. They have a very limited number of similar-looking options, but there is no way to customize the graphics.

Comment: See here http://www.addthis.com/help/toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Try [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) - it is a free service that allows you to embed a ton of these things pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this is not what I'm lookng for.

Answer (score 0):

You should not reinvent the wheel. There are plenty of tools that already do this, as well as keeping the information up-to-date for you.

http://sharethis.com/ is the first one I found on Google.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this is not what I'm looking for. It's not that I want to reinvent the wheel, but I want not to depend on an external service, and I want to be able to customize the graphics.

Comment: @Andrea, congrats on your insistence on doing exactly what you want. This is the only way I code web sites. I don't throw a bunch of plugins up there and call it good. Code it exactly how you want.

Answer (score 0):

AddThis and ShareThis have +350 ways of sharing links to your site.
If you don't want to depend on them, I'm afraid you *do* have to reinvent the wheel.

Check out the API:s of [FaceBook](http://developers.facebook.com/) and [Twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/doc) to start with.

Then continue with the rest, or surrender to [AddThis](http://addthis.com/).

On Facebook's developer pages (link above), it's very easy to find this example (which I assume is what you want, but for *all* social networks):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Great Web page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"><iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Have you inspected the javascripts from AddThis and ShareThis yet?

Good luck!

Comment: I have implemented this long ago. The only information I needed was the actual URLs, which noone actually provided. So I resorted to finding them on my own. Thank you for your advice anyway. :-)